# where do I enable Application Menus (Ubuntu MATE 18)

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

Windowed Applications do not have the traditional *File*, *Edit*, *View*, and etcetera.  This usually sits at the top of the Application, under the Title bar.

How do I enable Application Menus in Ubuntu MATE 18?

### setup

#### gsettings

```
$ gsettings get org.mate.panel default-layout
'familiar'
```

#### MATE Tweak

[image: MATE Tweak Panel]

[image: MATE Tweak Widnows]

Comment: What is your current MATE panel layout? Please add screenshot from MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`, Panel tab) or output of `gsettings get org.mate.panel default-layout` to the question.

Comment: The *Familiar* layout do not have global application menu on the top MATE Panel. You can compare it with *Contemporary* layout to understand what I mean. Which application do not have top menu? Does Caja (default MATE file-manager) have [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWp07.png) (*File*, *Edit*, *VIew*, etc)?